# how to set up "scripts" pacage for atom editor to run Java?

Tags: java, atom-editor

I've installed the package but can not figure out where to put input variables for my code.

for code

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double num0;
    num0 = Math.random();
    double num1 = Math.random();
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
    System.out.println(num0);
    System.out.println(num1 * 10 * Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
  }
}
```

the output is:

```
warning: [path] bad path element "undefined": no such file or directory
1 warning
Hello, World
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:8)
0.1272503287327883
[Finished in 1.713s]
```

seems the script lacks `args[0]` to perform the second `prntln` method

Comment: Are you expecting `args` to have values? If so, why?

Comment: just wondering how to pass them to script. when lounching compiled script from command promt they're just being added after script name: PS C:\Users\digit\documents> java HelloWorld **10**

Comment: the question is - how to pass comand line argument to Atom